# I got an error on my react and Node.js application

Tags: node.js, reactjs

When i'm trying to delete data from my react.js it shows this error and data is not deleted from database.

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE
> "... is not valid JSON

```
if (agree) {
            fetch(`http://localhost:5000/users/${user._id}`, {
                method: 'DELETE'
            })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data =>

                    //     if (data.deleteCound > 0) {
                    //     alert('User Deleted Successfully')
                    // }
                    console.log(data)
                );
        }
```

Comment: can u please add some code here

Comment: Show code. We can't help without it

Comment: if (agree) {
            fetch(`http://localhost:5000/users/${user._id}`, {
                method: 'DELETE'
            })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data =>

                    //     if (data.deleteCound > 0) {
                    //     alert('User Deleted Successfully')
                    // }
                    console.log(data)
                );
        }